# What does it mean to assign (2, 6, 8) to an integer in C?

Tags: c, comma-operator

What will be the output of the below piece of code? Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int x = (2,6,8);
   printf("%d",x);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run it?

Comment: `(2,6,8)`is using the [*comma* operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code

```
int x = (2, 6, 8);
```

uses the (very uncommon) ***comma operator***. In C, an expression of the form

```
expr1, expr2, expr3, ..., exprN
```

is interpreted to mean "evaluate `expr1` and discard its value, then evaluate `expr2` and discard its value, ..., and finally evaluate `exprN` and *use the value it evaluates to*." So in your case, the expression `(2, 6, 8)` means "evaluate 2 and discard its value, then evaluate 6 and discard its value, and finally evaluate 8 and use its value." That means that `x` gets the value `8`.

This code is almost certainly an error as written, since it doesn't make sense to evaluate 2 and 6 and discard their values. While it's rare to ever see the comma operator, it's most commonly used in contexts where the expressions have side effects, as in

```
for (x = 0; x < 5; x++, i++) { // Increment both x and i

}

while (x = readValue(), x != 0 && x < 15) { // Read a value into x, then check it

}
```

Comment: The whole concept doesn’t make sense to me. Sounds pointless. Interesting though.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Pointless what? The comma operator? Well, it is nice to have a comma operator to have several expressions  counted as one (as in  the `for` loop example) And then, an operator has to return a value. The choice of the last one is quite arbitrary though.

Comment: The for loop makes sense. But the sample in the question doesn’t.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Sure, but you said "the whole concept" :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be 8 because the comma act as operator

Comment: It does not act as an operator. It *is* an operator.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Operators act as operators.

Answer (score 1):

8. Compiler will evaluate the values one by one return the last evaluated value i.e. 8.