# Is there a special use of the parenthesis operator in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, initialization, declaration, comma-operator

The following code works fine, but I don't find a basis on which I can initialize the array with `()`. Can someone explain it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int a[3][2] = {(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)};
    printf("%#x\n", a[0]);
    printf("%#x\n", a[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the code works fine, what is the problem?

Comment: Just couple of questions earlier than this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66958020/what-does-it-mean-to-assign-2-6-8-to-an-integer-in-c

Comment: @Eugene This post solved my doubts, thank you very much

Comment: It would be great if someone who understands the problem updated the question so that it actually describes the problem, so that it will be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 4):

The `(0, 1)` expression uses the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). And it can be optimized to 1.

Read for more [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and some C standard like [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or newer.

You probably want to code:

```
int a[3][2] = {{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}};
```

And

```
printf("%#x\n", a[0]);
```

is wrong, you are printing a pointer. So use `%p` not `%#x`

If you compiled with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` you are getting warnings:

```
 % gcc -Wall -Wextra -g /tmp/articfox.c -o /tmp/articfox
 /tmp/articfox.c: In function ‘main’:
 /tmp/articfox.c:4:22: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
     4 |     int a[3][2] = {(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)};
       |                      ^
 /tmp/articfox.c:4:30: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
     4 |     int a[3][2] = {(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)};
       |                              ^
 /tmp/articfox.c:4:38: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
     4 |     int a[3][2] = {(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)};
       |                                      ^
 /tmp/articfox.c:4:19: warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]
     4 |     int a[3][2] = {(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)};
       |                   ^
       |                    {             } {     }
 /tmp/articfox.c:5:15: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     5 |     printf("%#x\n", a[0]);
       |             ~~^     ~~~~
       |               |      |
       |               |      int *
       |               unsigned int
       |             %#ls
 /tmp/articfox.c:6:15: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
     6 |     printf("%#x\n", a[1]);
       |             ~~^     ~~~~
       |               |      |
       |               |      int *
       |               unsigned int
       |             %#ls
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no parentheses operator in C.:)

If you remove the parentheses then the initialization of an array will look like

```
int a[3][2] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

That is the initializer list contains exactly 6 explicit initializers.

The parentheses allow you to use a more complex expression as an initializer. Thus in this declaration

```
int a[3][2] = {(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5)};
```

there are only 3 explicit initializers. All other elements of the array except the first three will be zero initialized.

The expressions in the parentheses are expressions with the comma operator. The value of each expression is the value of the right-most operand. So the above declaration is equivalent to

```
int a[3][2] = { 1, 3, 5 };
```

Consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int i = 10;
    int x = ( i++, ++i );
    
    printf( "x = %d\n", x );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
x = 12
```

If to remove the parentheses in this declaration

```
    int x = i++, ++i;
```

then the compiler will think that in the list of identifiers that you want to declare you forgot a second identifier after the comma something like

```
    int x = i++, y = ++i;
```